# How to cast a double to an int in Java by rounding it down?

Tags: java, casting

I need to cast a double to an int in Java, but the numerical value must always round down. i.e. 99.99999999 -> 99

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert float to int with Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295424/how-to-convert-float-to-int-with-java)

Comment: I believe that floats and doubles are different data types in Java.

Comment: I think they're too close because both are primitives and floating point types. Answers are the same and are very likely to continue being so.

Comment: Actually, the floating point question is more accurately asking how to round a float (as per some unspecified rounding standard). This question, which could probably be renamed more appropriately to 'How to round a double towards zero and cast to int in Java?' is similar to asking how to floor a double, except that flooring rounds to negative infinity rather than towards zero. The answers are quite different although the titles of the questions are similar.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

Casting to an int implicitly drops any decimal. No need to call Math.floor() (assuming positive numbers)

Simply typecast with (int), e.g.:

```
System.out.println((int)(99.9999)); // Prints 99
```

This being said, it does have a different behavior from `Math.floor` which rounds towards negative infinity (@Chris Wong)

Comment: Note that `Math.floor` *does* produce a different result for negative numbers than a simple typecast.

Comment: It depends on what the OP means by "round down". The cast rounds it "down" toward zero, while Math.floor rounds towards negative infinity.

Comment: Also note that an int cannot represent all the possible integer values that a double can.  If you wish to truncate a double-precision value, then cast to a 64-bit integer value like long.  `System.out.println((long)(9.9999e300));`

Comment: Although IEEE 754 [rounding rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#Rounding_rules) uses the term *truncation* for round-towards-zero, and uses the synonymous terms *round down* and *floor* for round-towards-negative-infinity, Java's [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#field.summary) and [`RoundingMode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#enum.constant.summary) classes uses `ROUND_DOWN` for round-towards-zero and `ROUND_FLOOR` for round-towards-negative-infinity.

Answer (score 34):

**To cast a double to an int and have it be rounded to the nearest integer** (i.e. unlike the typical `(int)(1.8)` and `(int)(1.2)`, which will both "round down" towards 0 and return `1`), **simply add 0.5 to the `double` that you will typecast to an `int`**.

For example, if we have

```
double a = 1.2;
double b = 1.8;
```

Then the following typecasting expressions for x and y and will return the rounded-down values (`x = 1` and `y = 1`):

```
int x = (int)(a);   // This equals (int)(1.2) --> 1
int y = (int)(b);   // This equals (int)(1.8) --> 1
```

But by adding 0.5 to each, we will obtain the **rounded-to-closest-integer result** that we may desire in some cases (`x = 1` and `y = 2`):

```
int x = (int)(a + 0.5);   // This equals (int)(1.8) --> 1
int y = (int)(b + 0.5);   // This equals (int)(2.3) --> 2
```

*As a small note*, this method also allows you to control the *threshold* at which the `double` is rounded up or down upon `(int)` typecasting.

```
(int)(a + 0.8);
```

to typecast. This will only round up to `(int)a + 1` whenever the decimal values are greater than or equal to 0.2. That is, by adding 0.8 to the `double` immediately before typecasting, 10.15 and 10.03 will be rounded down to 10 upon `(int)` typecasting, but 10.23 and 10.7 will be rounded up to 11.

Comment: You're completely right, it doesn't. I saw that this thread pops up when Google-ing for "Java int typecast double," and figured that someone looking for a way to round up/down directly with the (int) typecast could use this. This isn't posted using a stackoverflow account (so I'm not trying to boost my reputation, if that's taken seriously here), just trying to help spread a cool trick I use quite often. :) Cheers!

Comment: Nice but remember this works only with **positive** doubles. For instance, if you round -0.8 with this trick, then the code `System.out.println(""+ (int)(-0.8d + 0.5))` prints  0, instead of -1 as expected

Answer (score 19):

`(int)99.99999`

It will be 99. 
Casting a double to an int does not round, it'll discard the fraction part.

Comment: and if it's -99.99999.9 it will round up

Answer (score 13):

```
Math.floor(n)
```

where n is a double.  This'll actually return a double, it seems, so make sure that you typecast it after.

Comment: No need to floor before cast, see Xorlev's answer.

Comment: @miz: The semantics are different for negative numbers, though.

Answer (score 5):

This works fine `int i = (int) dbl;`

Answer (score 5):

`new Double(99.9999).intValue()`

Answer (score 1):

try with this, This is simple

```
double x= 20.22889909008;
int a = (int) x;

this will return a=20
```

or try with this:-

```
Double x = 20.22889909008;
Integer a = x.intValue();

this will return a=20
```

or try with this:-

```
double x= 20.22889909008;
System.out.println("===="+(int)x);

this will return ===20
```

may be these code will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Math.floor.

Answer (score 0):

In this question:

1.Casting double to integer is very easy task.

2.But it's not rounding double value to the nearest decimal. Therefore casting can be done like this:

```
double d=99.99999999;
int i=(int)d;
System.out.println(i);
```

and it will print `99`, but rounding hasn't been done.

Thus for rounding we can use,

```
double d=99.99999999;
System.out.println( Math.round(d));
```

This will print the output of `100`.