# How do I cast a double to an int in Java?

Tags: java

I'm looking at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html

I am trying

```
    double b = Math.sqrt(absoluteNumber);
    int c = b.intValue();
```

but I am getting this error:

```
Factorise.java:13: error: double cannot be dereferenced
int c = b.intValue();
```

Help please?

Comment: `int c = (int)b;`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to cast a double to an int in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143476/how-to-cast-a-double-to-an-int-in-java)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`double` is not an object, it is a primitive type.

Simply writing `(int)b` will do the job.

If you really need a `Double` object, you need to construct one.

Answer (score 6):

`double` is a "primitive type", it doesn't have an `intValue()` method (in fact it doesn't have *any* methods, as it is a primitive). Try the [Double](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html) wrapper class, which has an `intValue()` method.

```
Double b = Math.sqrt(absoluteNumber);
int c = b.intValue();
```

Or simply use casting:

```
double b = Math.sqrt(absoluteNumber);
int c = (int) b;
```

Comment: Using `Double` in this case is overkill, casting would be better.

Comment: @A.R.S. true, i was actually pointing the mistake, however, i mentioned about primitive castingin my answer now cheers :)

Answer (score 3):

You may simply cast it:

```
int c = (int)b;
```

Answer (score 1):

The specific compile time error in your class is the result of trying to call a method on a value which was declared as a primitive type.
Primitive types are not `Object`s and thus do not have properties. Hence they do not have any methods.

You could either cast the primitive `double` value to a primitive `int`value,

```
double b = Math.sqrt(absoluteNumber) ;
int a = (int) b ;
```

or cast the `double` to a `Double`---using a Java feature called *auto-boxing*---in order to use the `intValue` method of the `Number` interface implemented by the `Double` class:

```
double b = Math.sqrt(absoluteNumber) ;
int a = ( (Double) b ).intValue( ) ;
```

Another way is to use the `valueOf` and `intValue` methods of the `Double` class:

```
double b = Math.sqrt(absoluteNumber) ;
int a = ( Double.valueOf(b) ).intValue( ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Double  b = Math.sqrt(43253);
        int c = b.intValue();

        System.out.println("#### S = " + c);

    }
```

**Output**

```
#### S = 207
```

Comment: Using `Double` in this case is overkill, casting would be better.

Comment: Still this can also be considered as an option

Answer (score 0):

This simple line will do the job.

```
integer_var_name = (int) double_var_name;
```