# What does -1+ (int) mean?

Tags: java

I have a line of code in java, but I don't know how to explain how it works, someone knows what the -1+ (int) means

```
-1+ (int) ((Math.random () * (3)));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `(int)` actually goes with the next portion of code: it casts the result of `((Math.random () * (3)))` to an integer. (This will simply [drop the decimal portion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143476/how-to-cast-a-double-to-an-int-in-java-by-rounding-it-down); it will *not* round).

`Math.random()` returns a number that is greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0.

`((Math.random () * (3)))` simply returns a `double` that is greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 3.0, which will, as I just mentioned, subsequently be cast to an `int`. (This will result in a number between 0 and 2; 3 isn't possible).

Adding -1 to something is equivalent to subtracting 1.

So, this will result in a random integer between -1 and 1 (inclusive).

Answer (score 2):

> someone knows what the -1+ (int) means

This is the wrong way to look at it. Instead, you should break it down this way:

The `+` is adding two things together. On the left we have `-1` a literal integer. On the right we have `(int) ((Math.random () * (3)))`. Now we can break down what's in the parentheses. First we multiple two values, the result of `Math.random()` and the value (3)`. The result is a floating point number and the` (int)` casts it to an integer.

Answer (score 1):

> What does -1+ (int) mean?

You are having problems understanding this is because you haven't grasped Java precedence rules and (apparently) what a type-cast looks like.

Lets start with this part:

```
((Math.random () * (3)))
```

That means:

- call the `Math.random()` method
- multiply the result by 3.

Note that there some extra parentheses here that aren't necessary.  We could just write it as:

```
(Math.random() * 3)
```

Now lets look at the original expression:

```
-1 + (int) ((Math.random() * (3)));
```

In the above `(int)` means type-cast.  Cast the type of the "following" to the type in the parentheses.  In this case, it says
"cast the random number multiplied by 3 to an `int`".  That will perform a primitive conversion of that value to `int`.

Next, the `-1` means the number "minus one", and the `+` means addition.  So the whole thing means

> Add -1 to a random number multiplied by 3 and converted to an integer.

What is the conversion actually there for?

Well `Math.random()` actually produces a `double` value between `0.0` (inclusive) and `1.0` (exclusive).  And multiplying that by `3` gives another `double` value.  So the `(int)` cast is converting the `double` to an `int`.

Which tells us the complete meaning of that expression:

> Generate a random integer in the range -1 to +1.

---

I mentioned the *precedence rules*.  These are the rules that (in effect tell you what the subexpressions are.  For example

```
a * b + c
```

means

```
(a * b) + c
```

because `*` has higher precedence than `+`.

So in our example we have the following operators:

- The `-` in `-1` is a unary minus (negation)
- The `+` is binary plus (addition)
- The `(int)` is a type cast
- The `Math.random()` is a method call
- The `*` is a binary multiplication
- The `( ... )` are parentheses.

The order of precedence for these operators is

- parentheses highest
- method call
- negation
- type cast
- multiplication
- addition

So you can see that we **needed** the outside parentheses in `(Math.random() * 3)` so that the type cast applies to the product rather than (just) result of the method call.

Here is a table showing the precedence of all operators (and similar) in Java 11:

- [Operator precedence in Java](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/)