# How do I round a Vector3F to an integer vector?

Tags: java

I am currently making a program to build up and knock down blocks. It's simple but fun. I have gotten pretty far but have hit a snag.

So far, I have it so that when I click, it creates a block at the position I am looking at, either on another block or the ground. This is achieved through the use of ray tracing from the camera and creating a block at a Vector3F created from the collision between the ray and the other object. What I can't do is round the Vector3F so that the numbers are all single digit integers. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: You should let us know which library you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Math.round():
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round(float)

Examples:
1:

```
// It will round the floats in Vector3F and leave the results as floats
Vector3F vect = new Vector3F(2.3f, 1.114124f, 0f);
vect.x = Math.round(vect.x); // 2f
vect.y = Math.round(vect.x); // 1f
vect.z = Math.round(vect.x); // 0f
```

2:

```
// It will round the floats in Vector3F and leave the results as ints
Vector3F vect = new Vector3F(2.3f, 1.114124f, 0f);
int x = Math.round(vect.x);
int y = Math.round(vect.x);
int z = Math.round(vect.x);
```

There is also more info: [How to convert float to int with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295424/how-to-convert-float-to-int-with-java)