# How to turn a float into an int

Tags: java, floating-point, int

have a decimal float from a user input calculation, say 2.856 that I need to turn into the integer 2.

Note, this has to be done in the code itself and cannot simply be output with %.0f; I need it for future calculations.

Additional Note, I have used

```
float Var1;
int Var2;
Var1 = 2.856;
Var2 = (int)Var1;
```

And if this is the easiest way to do it, please explain how (int) works, because I have no idea.

EDIT: Okay, so I was a little unclear in my explination, Var 1 = 2.856 is already determined  by the code. I don't actually type out any numbers here; so using that I need to turn Var1 into Var2. So I can't type in code

```
Var2=(int)2.856
```

because 2.856 changes all the time.
Can I do

```
Var2=(int)Var1?
```

Or anything to that extent?

Comment: It's called a _cast_.

Comment: You don't *have* a decimal. You have a *floating-point variable,* of type 'float'.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert float to int with Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295424/how-to-convert-float-to-int-with-java)

Answer (score 0):

You have to put an `f` after the number, so it's treated as a `float` and not as a `double`:

```
var1 = 2.856f;
```

then cast it to a `int`:

```
var2 = (int)var1;
```

**`(int) number`**: This is called casting (can be made with other primitive types, also with classes). When casting a number to `int`, it get rid of the non-integer part (after the dot), and just returns the integer part.

**Note:** I would recommend you to follow Java naming conventions. Your variables should be named like `nameOfVariable`, while classes should be named like `NameOfClass`.

Answer (score 0):

```
float f = 2.345F;
in i = (int) f;
```

It's as easy as that. 
And yes, if this wasn't clear; you are required to place an F behind the value for floating-point numbers, otherwise it will be interpreted as a double.

Answer (score 0):

That is indeed the easiest way to do it.  What `(int)` does is "cast" the float variable to an integer form.  Since float variables cannot be stored as integers normally due to the decimal point, the `(int)` "casts" the float to an integer by truncating the decimal part away.  Since you're working in java, it's also a good idea to follow java naming conventions, which in this case means you should start your variable names with lowercase letters.