# Convert a float to int

Tags: java

```
Android Studio 0.5.2
```

Hello,

I have a random float value that I want to convert to an int.

The float could have a random number between `-9.4182062E-9` to `9.593071E-8`.

I just want to get the positive int number so if the number is negative i.e. `-5.5115866E-8` it should just return 5. I have used the Math.abs for this.

I have tried the following:

```
int accel =  (int)Math.abs(randomAccel);
```

However, `accel` keeps giving me a zero no matter what value `randomAccel` is.

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1295424/2282538

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your negative number `-5.485747E-5` finish by `E-5` meaning that it is `-0.0000548574`
So the absolute value is `0.0000548574`.

So `Math.abs(-0.0000548574)` is `0.0000548574`

`(int)0.0000548574` is `0`

result is `0`

Are your sure your code is responding `0` no matter the value of random? Check the number you are trying to convert.

You should unit test your code with your values.

Answer (score 1):

Your random number range has very small a magnitude (negative exponents) - importantly it is less than `+/-1`. When `float` is cast to `int`, all fractional parts are *truncated*, thus every number in your range, after setting the sign to positive, will result in `0` if cast to `int`.

It seems like you want to ignore the exponent of your numbers. One way to do that would be:

```
int accel = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(randomAccel).replaceAll("-?(\\d+).*", "$1"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 int accel = (int)Math.abs(randomAccel);
```

This line performs 3 steps

1. Get the absolute value of `randomAccel`
2. Cast the value to an `int` (floating point numbers are truncated)
3. Assign the `int` value to `accel`

Now lets look what happens when the input is in the range `[-9.4182062E-9,9.593071E-
8]` (By the way `-5.485747E-5` is not in this range.)

```
Input value -9.4E-9 = -0.0000000094

1. -9.4E-9 converted to 9.4E-9
2. 9.4E-9 cast to int, fractional part is removed. Value is 0
3. 0 is assigned to `accel`
```

If you just want to most significant digit, you could multiply by `10^8` and see if that value is greater than `0`, if it is then trucate, else multiply by 10 then truncate:

```
int accel = 0;
r = Math.abs( randomAccel ) * 100000000;
if( r >= 10 ) {/* error out of range */}
else if( r > 0 ) accel = (int)r;
else
{
    r *= 10;
    accel = (int)r;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import static java.lang.Math.*;
```

Convert part:

```
double input =-5.485747E-5; //for example
double tmp = abs(input);
tmp *= pow(10, abs(floor(log10(tmp))));
int out = (int) tmp;
System.out.println(out);
```

output:

```
5
```