# Android Material Slider get value

Tags: android, material-components-android

I'm trying to use the new
Material Slider but I don't know if there is a way that I can get the value of the slider programmatically as a Integer.

I need the value as Integer because I have to work with the value doing some arithmetic calculations.

I get the value in float. How can I convert it to a Integer?

```
slider.addOnChangeListener(new Slider.OnChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onValueChange(@NonNull Slider slider, float value, boolean fromUser) {
        //Use the value
    }
});
```

Comment: You are given the value as a float... convert it into a int value that makes sense for your calculations

Comment: @DevWithZachary how can I do this?

Comment: I tried with a Toast message with (int)myvalue and it doesn't work

Comment: The simplest way would be to cast it `int i = (int) value` but it will depend how you want to handle values, for example 1.999999 would be cast to 1 as an int

Comment: what do you mean it doesn't work? be specific and provide error messages in your question

Comment: @Giovanni I have posted answer, kindly check and upvote if it helps you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert float to int with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295424/how-to-convert-float-to-int-with-java)

Comment: Thanks, I just saw that I was forgotting to parse the result as String and not as a Float value.

Answer (score 3):

You have got the value of the slider. You have to convert it to a Integer. For converting float into integer, follow below code:

```
slider.addOnChangeListener(new Slider.OnChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onValueChange(@NonNull Slider slider, float value, boolean fromUser) {
        Integer slide_value = Math.round(value); 
    }
});
```

NOTE: Using Math.round() will round the float to the nearest integer.